# How to update Xamarin.Forms to latest version?

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

I'm starting to work with Xamarin.Forms for the first time. I noticed I might have an outdated version in my project though, and I can't find how to update it.

Looking at the NuGet gallery, the latest version is 1.5:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

However, in my project, I'm still using version 1.3 somehow, even though I created the project only a few days ago. Here's what the solution explorer looks like:

[image: Solution explorer]

Xamarin Studio won't let me update the references because they are "from packages". What does that mean and how can I update?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From menu click **Project->Update Nuget Packages** then  it will check updates(can be check from status bar at top side of editor). When it finished the update checking process go to Packages from solution explorer. You'll see the (1 update notification). Right click the package and update.

It's that simple.

Comment: Ah, yeah... Dead easy indeed, crazy I didn't see it! Thanks :)

Comment: Minor note: Project - Update NuGet Packages will update all the NuGet packages in the project. It will not just check for updates. The check for updates is done in the background when the solution is opened. The check for updates is automatic but can be disabled in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Xamarin.Forms as a NuGet package, so you have to go under Package, not Reference, and Add Package

Answer (score 0):

As for August 2019, you can go to your Forms project in `Solution` window, open `Dependencies > NuGet` and right click on `Xamarin.Forms` and then click `Update` if you want to only update `Xamarin.Forms`. Remember about doing it for 3 projects: `*.Forms`, `*.Forms.Android` and `*.Forms.iOS`.

`Project->Update Nuget Packages` will update everything which is not always desired